# When I try to run my application of submition data in SQLite there is an error 1 syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, compiler-errors, compilation, syntax-error

My query is

```
String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE" +DATABASE_Bussiness+ "(" + KEY_ID +
    "INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, " + A_DATE + "TEXT,
    " + A_NAME+ "TEXT, " +A_AMOUNT+ "INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE);
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are receiving also, this would help people to understand the issue better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive

> android.database.sqlite.[**`SQLiteException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException)

A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution. Rectify your query. Need Spacing.

Try with

```
String CREATE ="CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_Bussiness + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + A_DATE + " TEXT, "
                + A_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + A_AMOUNT + " INTEGER "
                + ")";
```

**Clean-Rebuild-Uninstall App and Run again**.

Comment: @AsfandCataLyst problem for `;";` two semi colons.

Comment: @AsfandCataLyst Kindly check edited code. Uninstall old app and run

Comment: just thankx its working know can you tell me what was error?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a space between the column names and the type. E.g. `A_NAME + "TEXT..."`. It should be `A_NAME + " TEXT..."` (see space before TEXT).

Also between CREATE and the table name `"CREATE TABLE" +DATABASE_Bussiness`. Note that the space before the `+` is not within the string literal. Spaces outside the string literals a irrelevant. `"a"+"b"` is the same as `"a"  +  "b"`. Both result in `"ab"`. But  `"a " + "b"` gives `"a b"`.

You could also use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) ($) and a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) (@). This is more readable

```
String CREATE = $@"CREATE TABLE {DATABASE_Bussiness} (
    {KEY_ID} INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
    {A_DATE} TEXT,
    {A_NAME} TEXT,
    {A_AMOUNT} INTEGER);";
db.execSQL(CREATE);
```

Also, the variables must contain column names  and not column values. Values are inserted into the table after it has been created with the [INSERT INTO](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/) command. The result should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Deposit (  
    DepositId INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,  
    Valuta TEXT,  
    Descrition TEXT,  
    Amount INTEGER);
```

Table and column names should not be keywords belonging to the SQLite language.

Comment: Can you show the resulting string and the error message?